# Post-request returns null for child entities

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, postman, h2

When I post objects manually through Java I get the desired result in Postman which is that the parent/child-entities have the correct corresponding @OneToMany/@ManyToOne bi-directional relationship with foreign keys as the following two images show:

[Main-class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZSoJ0.png)

[Postman Get-request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f6kTK.png)

Now if I post an object through Postman where I want the similar relationship between parent/child entities it looks like this:

[Postman Post-request and response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/isAb8.png)

[Updated Postman Get-request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZVBU8.png)

As you can see the "categories" object with the user "Erik" is returned as an empty array and if I look at my H2 Database I can see that the foreign keys CATEGORY_ID and USER_ID are both set as null. This is my question. How do I make sure the correct relationship is established through my controllers?

[H2 Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cTkrP.png)

My Controllers look like this:

[User Controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3KUme.png)

[Category Controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qMJY9.png)

[Expense Controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cpGWQ.png)

I assume that my controllers are lacking but I don't really know what is missing. The methods that are responsible for the the posts are createUser, createCategory and createExpense.

Feel free to criticise my code and come with suggestions in general! Thank you!

Comment: Can you post the entities?

Comment: it has to do with how you have defined your models. try to look in to the models file and check if you have defined all the constraints properly.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answers! Here are the entities as requested!

https://gitlab.com/hambe-learning/expense-tracker-using-react-and-spring-boot/-/tree/master/src/main/java/com/example/codeengine/expense/model